# Making a dictionary from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have been unable to figure this out, I think the problem might be in the way I am making the list of lists. Can anyone help out? Thanks!

My desired outcome is

codondict = {'A': ['GCT','GCC','GCA','GCG'], 'C': ['TGT','TGC'], &c

but what i get is:

{'A': 'A', 'C': 'C', &c.

Here's my terminal:

> > > A=['GCT','GCC','GCA','GCG']
> > >
> > > C=['TGT','TGC']
> > >
> > > D=['GAT','GAC']
> > >
> > > E=['GAA','GAG']
> > >
> > > F=['TTT','TTC']
> > >
> > > G=['GGT','GGC','GGA','GGG']
> > >
> > > H=['CAT','CAC']
> > >
> > > I=['ATT','ATC','ATA']
> > >
> > > K=['AAA','AAG']
> > >
> > > L=['TTA','TTG','CTT','CTC','CTA','CTG']
> > >
> > > M=['ATG']
> > >
> > > N=['AAT','AAC']
> > >
> > > P=['CCT','CCC','CCA','CCG']
> > >
> > > Q=['CAA','CAG']
> > >
> > > R=['CGT','CGC','CGA','CGG','AGA','AGG']
> > >
> > > S=['TCT','TCC','TCA','TCG','AGT','AGC']
> > >
> > > T=['ACT','ACC','ACA','ACG']
> > >
> > > V=['GTT','GTC','GTA','GTG']
> > >
> > > W=['TGG']
> > >
> > > Y=['TAT','TAC']
> > >
> > > aminoacids=['A','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','K','L','M','N','P','Q','R','S','T','V','W','Y']
> > >
> > > from collections import defaultdict
> > >
> > > codondict=defaultdict(list)
> > >
> > > for i in aminoacids:
> > >
> > > ...     for j in i:(ALSO TRIED for j in list(i))
> > >
> > > ...      ...       codondict[i]=j
> > >       ...
> > >
> > > codondict
> > >
> > > defaultdict(, {'A': 'A', 'C': 'C', 'E': 'E', 'D': 'D', 'G': 'G', 'F': 'F', 'I': 'I', 'H': 'H', 'K': 'K', 'M': 'M', 'L': 'L', 'N': 'N', 'Q': 'Q', 'P': 'P', 'S': 'S', 'R': 'R', 'T': 'T', 'W': 'W', 'V': 'V', 'Y': 'Y'})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
condondict= dict(A=['GCT','GCC','GCA','GCG'],
C=['TGT','TGC'],
D=['GAT','GAC'],
E=['GAA','GAG'],
F=['TTT','TTC'],
G=['GGT','GGC','GGA','GGG'],
H=['CAT','CAC'],
I=['ATT','ATC','ATA'],
K=['AAA','AAG'],
L=['TTA','TTG','CTT','CTC','CTA','CTG'],
M=['ATG'],
N=['AAT','AAC'],
P=['CCT','CCC','CCA','CCG'],
Q=['CAA','CAG'],
R=['CGT','CGC','CGA','CGG','AGA','AGG'],
S=['TCT','TCC','TCA','TCG','AGT','AGC'],
T=['ACT','ACC','ACA','ACG'],
V=['GTT','GTC','GTA','GTG'],
W=['TGG'],
Y=['TAT','TAC'])
```

The reason to use `defaultdict()` is to allow access/creation of dictionary values without causing a KeyError, or by-pass using the form:

```
if key not in mydict.keys():
    mydict[key] = []
mydict[key].append(something)
```

If your not creating new keys dynamically, you don't really need to use `defaultdict()`.

Also if your keys already represent the *aminoacids*, you and just iterate over the keys themselves.

```
for aminoacid, sequence in condondict.iteritems():
    # do stuff with with data...
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do what you need is using the [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) function, which returns a dictionary containing the whole set of variables of the local scope, with the variable names as the keys and its contents as values.

```
for i in aminoacids:
    codondict[i] = locals()[i]
```

So, you could get the `A` list, for example, using: `locals()['A']`.

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of verbose, and is confusing the name of a variable `'A'` with its value `A`. Keeping to what you've got:

```
aminoacids = { 'A': A, 'C': C, 'D': D ... }
```

should get you the dictionary you ask for:

```
{ 'A' : ['GCT', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCG'], 'C' : ['TGT', 'TGC'], ... }
```

where the order of keys `'A'` and `'C'` may not be what you get back because dictionaries are not ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use globals() built-in too, and dict comprehension:

```
codondict = {k:globals()[k] for k in aminoacids}
```

it's better to rely on locals() instead of globals(), like stummjr's solution, but you can't do so with dict comprehension directly

```
codondict = dict([(k,locals()[k]) for k in aminoacids])
```

However you can do this:

```
loc = locals()
codondict = {k:loc[k] for k in aminoacids}
```

If you change dinamically your aminoacids list or the aminoacids assignments, it's better to use something lazier, like:

```
codondict = lambda: {k:globals()[k] for k in aminoacids}
```

with this last you can always use the updated dictionary, but it's now a callable, so use codondict()[x] instead of codondict[x] to get an actual dict. This way you can store the entire dict like hist = codondict() in case you need to compare different historical versions of codondict. That's small enough to be useful in interactive modes, but not recommended in bigger codes, though.